# postgresql Subselect Aggregate in larger query

Tags: postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm working with a gigantic dataset of individuals with demographic information and action tracking. I am trying to get the percentage of people who committed an action, which is simple, but also trying to get average ages of people who fit in a specific subgroup of the original SELECT. The CASE WHEN line works fine alone, and the subquery runs fine in it's own query but I cannot seem to get it integrated into this query as a subquery, it gives me a syntax error on the CASE WHEN statement. Here's a slightly anonymized version of the query. Any help would be VERY appreciated.

```
SELECT
    AVG(ageagg)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            age AS ageagg
        FROM
            agetable
        WHERE
            age>30
        AND action_taken=1) AvgAge_30Action,
    COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN action_taken=1
            AND age> 30
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0 NULL) / COUNT(
        CASE
            WHEN age>30) AS Over_30_Action
FROM
    agetable
WHERE
    website_type=3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've interpreted your intent correctly, you wish to compute the following:

1) the number of people over the age of 30 that took a specific action as a percentage of the total number of people over the age of 30

2) the average age of the people over the age of 30 that took a specific action

Assuming my interpretation is correct, this query might work for you:

```
SELECT
  100 * over_30_action / over_30_total AS percentage_of_over_30_took_action,
  average_age_of_over_30_took_action
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN action_taken=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS over_30_action,
    COUNT(*) AS over_30_total,
    AVG(CASE WHEN action_taken=1 THEN age ELSE NULL END)
      AS average_age_of_over_30_took_action
  FROM agetable
  WHERE website_type=3 AND age>30
) aggregated;
```

I created a dummy table and populated it with the following data.

```
postgres=# select * from agetable order by website_type, action_taken, age;
 age | action_taken | website_type
-----+--------------+--------------
  33 |            1 |            1
  32 |            1 |            2
  28 |            1 |            3
  29 |            1 |            3
  32 |            1 |            3
  33 |            1 |            3
  34 |            1 |            3
  32 |            2 |            3
  32 |            3 |            3
  33 |            4 |            3
  34 |            5 |            3
  33 |            6 |            3
  34 |            7 |            3
  35 |            8 |            3
(14 rows)
```

Of the 14 rows, 4 rows (the first four in this listing) have either the wrong `website_type` or have `age` below 30.  Of the ten remaining rows, you can see that 3 of them have an `action_taken` of 1.  So, the query should determine that 30% of folks over the age of 30 took a particular action, and the average age among that particular population should be 33 (ages 32, 33, and 34).  The results of the query I posted:

```
 percentage_of_over_30_took_action | average_age_of_over_30_took_action 
-----------------------------------+------------------------------------
                                30 |                33.0000000000000000
(1 row)
```

Again, all of this is predicated upon my interpretation of your intent actually being accurate.  This is of course based on a highly contrived data set, but hopefully it's enough of a functional signpost to get you on the right path.